# Can C# APIs act as datasource?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, olap-cube

I have a need for Multidimensional cube to fetch data from some C# APIs instead of a database. 
So I have 2 questions:

1. How to create such APIs. For this, what type of project i need to create in visual studio 2010? And what all APIs do I need to provide.
2. How to create such datasource connection (in Connection Manager) in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

seems you are looking for SOA, and one of my bookmarked writeup: http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/tutorials/introduction-129/soa-using-c-and-wcf-2307/